# Xcode 4.6 "No visable @interface for 'PlayingCardDeck' declares the selector 'addCard:AtTop:'

Tags: xcode, class-method, xcode4.6

I know this is a common problem, however I couldn't find the solution to mine.
I'm following cs193p Standford course, following letter by letter the code at the lecture slides, and Xcode 4.6 still produces an error witch didn't occur to Xcode 4.4.something...

PlayingCardDeck.h:

```
#import "Deck.h"

@interface PlayingCardDeck : NSObject

@end
```

PlayingCardDeck.m:

```
#import "PlayingCardDeck.h"
#import "PlayingCard.h"

@implementation PlayingCardDeck

...
                [self addCard:card atTop:YES]; //problem occurs here
...
@end
```

deck.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Card.h"

@interface Deck : NSObject

- (void)addCard:(Card *)card atTop:(BOOL)atTop;
...
@end
```

deck.m:

```
#import "Deck.h"

@interface Deck()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *cards;
@end

@implementation Deck
...
- (void)addCard:(Card *)card atTop:(BOOL)atTop
{
    if (atTop)
        [self.cards insertObject:card atIndex:0];
    else
        [self.cards addObject:card];
}
...
@end
```

By logic, addCard:atTop: should be a (+) method? In the lecture it was being a (-) just fine. In addition, after trying to change it to a (+) method, it creates 6 additional problems witch demand using entirely different syntax for each time I'm going for "self".
In short, I'm really confused by now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is addCard: atTop is a method of Deck, not a method ofPlayingCardDeck. 
Maybe PlayingCardDeck should inherit from Deck? Or there is an iVar of PlayingCardDeck which is a deck?

Comment: According to the lecture witch I'm learning from, importing deck should acquire playingCardDeck the methods of deck. In the method, playingCardDeck is creating each time a card variable, and then it should add it to self. The target of the method is to enter to itself all the 54 cards. So yes, PlayingCardDeck is creating a particular deck while the method deck's job is to do simple functions of editing any deck. So how can PlayingCardDeck could inherit these functions from deck if not by import?

Comment: @interface PlayingCardDeck : **Deck** This is the way you inherit ( you also need the import)!